# Hadoop Mapreduce CompileError with .addCacheFile (use external Jar)

Tags: java, hadoop, compilation, mapreduce

Since a few hours I try to get an external JAR into my code ... but I'm not lucky. So maybe someone here can help me. Anyway I use Hadoop 2.5.

I try to use this external JAR:

```
public class SampleAddition {
  private int firstVariable;
  private int secondVariable;

  public SampleAddition(int firstVariable, int secondVariable) {
      this.firstVariable = firstVariable;
      this.secondVariable = secondVariable;
  }

  public int getResult(){
      int result = firstVariable + secondVariable;
      return result;
  }
}
```

For the MapReduce-Code I used the simple WordCount example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class SampleAdditionMapRed {

 // Main-Method
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "SampleAddition MapReduce");

    // Set Classes
    job.setJarByClass(SampleAdditionMapRed.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    // Set Number of Reducer
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    // Set Output and Input Parameters
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    // Set FileDestination
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    // Set external Jar
    // Path pfad = new Path("/ClassFiles/SampleAddition.jar");
    // job.addCacheFile(pfad.toUri());

    // Run Job
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}


// Mapper
public static class MyMapper extends
        Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    // Initialize Variables
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    // Declare Map-Methode
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}

// Reducer
public static class MyReducer extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    // Declare Reduce-Method
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        // Set SampleAddition Class
        int value1 = 55;
        int value2 = 100;

        // Sum two Values with Class SampleAddition
        SampleAddition test = new SampleAddition(value1, value2);

        // Return summarized values
        int resultFromClass = 0;
        resultFromClass = test.getResult();

        // Output
        result.set(resultFromClass);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
  }
}
```

In the first try I put my external Jar on my singleNodeCluster in the following directory "/usr/lib/hadoop/". This was working. But with a big cluster it's not an option.

Then I tried to use the function job.addCacheFile(...) - the following two lines:

```
// Path pfad = new Path("/ClassFiles/SampleAddition.jar");
// job.addCacheFile(pfad.toUri());
```

But now when I try to compile this then I get the following error:

```
/root/MapReduce/SampleAdditionMapRed.java:40: error: cannot find
symbol
                job.addCacheFile(pfad.toUri());
                   ^   symbol:   method addCacheFile(URI)   location: variable job of type Job 1 error
```

The most solutions which I found on the internet was with Hadoop 1.x. 
I'm really thankful for any idea!

---

Add Compile Command:

```
javac -d CompileBin -classpath "/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*:/root/MapReduce/ClassFiles/SampleAddition.jar" /root/MapReduce/SampleAdditionMapRed.java    
jar cvf SampleAdditionMapRed.jar -C CompileBin .
```

Answer (score 0):

In Hadoop Gen 2, you could do it like

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(..);
```

See [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) for example.

Comment: I thought DistributedCache is an old feature from the 1.x. When I use this, then I get the Message "The type DistributedCache is deprecated". That's why I used the [Job-Class](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html)

Comment: Ahh sorry. Try out `job.addCacheFile(new Path(filename).toUri());`

Comment: That is the way I tried it (see the post above). With this I get the compile error.

Comment: I added the compile command at the end and the import statements

Comment: Do you mean import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;? Then I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no issue in the syntax.
Just cross check package import.

Job

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
```

and Path

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
```

Comment: Hi, could you double check your hadoop version.

Comment: are you able to compile now.